# Debian server, Node js Port 3000 listening But cant access via browser

Tags: node.js, express, debian

On my debian server, I installed node and then started node server on port 3000. The server is running, but it isn't visible from the browser

Now when I try to get it running via my domain or via my ip(for example xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000) or my domain (my-domain.com:3000) in both cases it doesn't work. I think I don't quite get the concept and I tried to search for a billion different things, but I can't find the solution to my problem. Could someone tell me, if I need to setup something else, too?

My server js code is

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
 
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
            io.sockets.emit( 'new_message', {
            message: data.message,
            date: data.date,
            msgcount: data.msgcount
            });
    });
});
```

[Error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnEGs.png)

Answer (score 0):

why are you using express and http both packages.

you can run server by either of them.

and then add a get route for it.

```js
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // ...
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // ...
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

I hope this will work!

Comment: your code giving an error  Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/usr/www/users/oompfcease/server.js:1
import { createServer } from "http";

Comment: When running on localhost, code works perfectly, but not when running on the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for GET requests in order to respond to them.

Try adding something like:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request test.')
})
```

In your case make sure you add the route before passing the `app` to the `http.createServer()` method, or otherwise just use something like `app.listen(3000)`.

More info in the docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: doesnt works  giving error
This site can’t be reached www.mydomainame:3000 took too long to respond.

Comment: Wait, are you running the server on localhost:3000 of a remote debian machine?

Comment: This is not on localhost, it is on my domainname

Comment: `Server.listen(3000)` === localhost:3000. You probably need a reverse proxy like NGINX to pass the requests off to the express server. Right now you are only listening to local requests on "your domainname". I don't know if that is a remote server or what...